# SRP login with Amazon Cognito from

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to make integrate cognito login in to a .net console app with the following code:

```
    public static async Task LoginAsync()
    {
        var credentials = new AnonymousAWSCredentials();
        using var client = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        var initAuthRequest = new InitiateAuthRequest();
        initAuthRequest.AuthParameters.Add("USERNAME", "myuser@myemail.com");
        initAuthRequest.AuthParameters.Add("SRP_A", "3ab487035b1635659eb0f349d2czab124d258b03725x5322138ff24ab5c870311b16585659eb0f349d2ceab124d258b0372555322138ff2");
        initAuthRequest.ClientId = "my_amazon_client_id";
        initAuthRequest.AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.USER_SRP_AUTH;
        var response = await client.InitiateAuthAsync(initAuthRequest);
    }
```

This works perfectly and I get a response with:

1. SALT
2. SECRET_BLOCK
3. SRP_B
4. USERNAME
5. USER_ID_FOR_SRP

According to the documentation I have to generate a `PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE` but I don't know how to generate it or what order the cryptographic functions should follow. I have tried to follow all the Amazon documentation but it's not well documented, and the only solutions I found rely on a `GetUserPoolId` that I don't know where to get it from. I saw another Xamrin.Forms tutorial but it's not exactly following this SRP way that I need.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE` is based on following into one base64-encoded string.

- `Let K_USER = SHA256_HASH(S_USER)` 
  Let S_USER = (SRP_B - k * gx)(a + ux)
  Let x = SHA256_HASH(salt + FULL_PASSWORD)
  Let u = SHA256_HASH(SRP_A + SRP_B)
  Let k = SHA256_HASH(N + g)
- When all MFA challenges are answered, Amazon Cognito responds with a `DeviceGroupKey` and a unique `DeviceKey` in the NewDeviceMetadataType field.
- For `PASSWORD_CLAIM_SECRET_BLOCK`, use the value of `SECRET_BLOCK`.
- For `TIMESTAMP`, include the current time. (For example, Tue Sep 25
  00:09:40 UTC 2018.)

```
Let PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE = SHA256_HMAC(K_USER, DeviceGroupKey + DeviceKey + PASSWORD_CLAIM_SECRET_BLOCK + TIMESTAMP), base64-encoded
```

Ref : [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-remembered-devices/), [Link2](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/6b87f1a30a998072b4d98facb49dcaf8780d15b0/lib/CognitoUser.js?#L299), [Link3](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1979)